# Не могу скачать virtualenv

Tags: python, windows, cmd, pip, virtualenv

Ошибка:

> error: can't create or remove files in install directory
>
> The following error occurred while trying to add or remove files in
>   the installation directory:
>
> ```
> [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Program Files\\Anaconda3\\Lib\\site-packages\\test-easy-install-4356.write-test'
> ```
>
> The installation directory you specified (via --install-dir, --prefix,
>   or the distutils default setting) was:
>
> ```
> C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\
> ```
>
> Perhaps your account does not have write access to this directory?  If
>   the installation directory is a system-owned directory, you may need
>   to sign in as the administrator or "root" account.  If you do not have
>   administrative access to this machine, you may wish to choose a
>   different installation directory, preferably one that is listed in
>   your PYTHONPATH environment variable.
>
> For information on other options, you may wish to consult the
>   documentation at:
>
> https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/easy_install.html
>
> Please make the appropriate changes for your system and try again.

Comment: От админа запускай

Comment: Спасибо уже, кстати помоги с этой проблемой плиз File "manage.py", line 17, in <module>
    "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?

Comment: P.S Я всё установил и виртуал и ещё какой-то виртуал

Comment: нужно отдельный вопрос задавать

Comment: Окей щас создам

Comment: На сайте новый вопрос создай

Comment: Я не могу. Нужно 40 мин ждать

Comment: Тут напиши ответ,а потом когда я задам,там напишишь

Answer (score 1):

Для возможности записи в program files программа должна быть запущена с правами администратора.